# Itemize left margin

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize

I'm using itemize with the option

```
[leftmargin=5.5mm]
```

How can I extend this option to all itemizes in the whole document? I'm on

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,book,twoside]
```

Thanks!

Comment: One start by posting a full minimal example instead of sniplets. For example `\documentclass` takes a mandatory argument, and standard `itemize` does not support `[leftmargin=5.5mm]`, thus there are things you are not telling us, thus impossible to help.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `enumitem` package to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=5.5mm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item hello
\item world
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea universally change this setting.
In particular, it will effect all list environments (such as `enumerate`d lists).

Alternatively, `\setlist` allows you specify for which type of list the parameters values should apply:

```
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=5.5mm}
```

In this case, `enumerate`d lists will not also be effected.

It would be better to define your own list environment.

`enumitem` provides some nice macros to tailor your own customized list:

```
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{3}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1in}
\setlist[myitemize,2]{label=$\rightarrow$,leftmargin=1em}
\setlist[myitemize,3]{label=$\diamond$}
```

which when called as

```
Here's an example of a user defined list using \verb=\newlist= and
\verb=\setlist=.  The first argument to \verb=\newlist= is the name of the new
list; the second argument is which type of list (\verb=itemize=,
\verb=enumerate=, or \verb=description=) to model the new list on; the third
argument specifies how many levels you need the list for.  Minimally, you must
then call \verb=\setlist= to set the \verb=label=s.
\begin{myitemize}
  \item hello
  \item world
  \begin{myitemize}
    \item hello
    \item world
    \begin{myitemize}
      \item hello
      \item world
    \end{myitemize}
  \end{myitemize}
\end{myitemize}
```

produces

[image]

Alternatively, you can also do this as:

```
\newenvironment{myitemize}
    {\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=5.5mm]}
    {\end{itemize}
```